# Sinon spy fails even though function spied on is being called

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I am having a problem understanding why a sinon spy is failing for me, even though the function I am spying on does get called during my test (which I proved with some simple console logging).

So say I have something as follows:

**index.js**

```
let MyModule = require('./src/index.js');

MyModule = new MyModule();

module.exports = {
  DoStuff: MyModule.DoStuff,
  doOtherStuff: MyModule.doOtherStuff,
};
```

**src/index.js**

```
const MyModule = function MyModule() {

  const self = this;

  self.doOtherStuff = function doOtherStuff() {
    console.log('doOtherStuff called!!!')
  }

  self.DoStuff = async function DoStuff() {
    const xhr = self.axiosInstance();
    await xhr.post()
      .then((res) => {
        self.doOtherStuff(res.data);
      })
      .catch((_err) => {
        console.log(_err);
      });
  };
}

module.exports = MyModule;
```

My test is as follows:

```
const nock = require('nock');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const MyModule = require('../index.js');
describe('When calling DoStuff succeeds in making the xhr call', () => {
        before(() => {
          nock(apiHostName)
            .post('/some-path')
            .reply(200, { foo: 'bar' });
        });
        it('should call doOtherStuff', async () => {
          const spy = sinon.spy(MyModule, 'doOtherStuff');
          await MyModule.DoStuff();
          sinon.assert.calledOnce(spy);
        });
      });
```

I am seeing the console log in my doOtherStuff function output in my test runner output, but the test fails saying the spy was called zero times.

I wondered if this down to the async nature of the code I am testing, but I have made sure to use async/await in my test to. I must be doing something stupid, where am I going wrong?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

So I tried stripping the functions back to something more basic, and now have the following:

```
const MyModule = function MyModule() {

  const self = this;

  self.doOtherStuff = function doOtherStuff() {
    console.log('doOtherStuff called!!!')
  }

  self.DoStuff = function DoStuff() {
    self.doOtherStuff();
  };
}

module.exports = MyModule;
```

So this will rule out any async/await problems I may be hitting.

But even when running the following simple test, the spy never gets called:

```
const MyModule = require('../index.js');

it('should call doOtherStuff', () => {
  const spy = sinon.spy(MyModule, 'doOtherStuff');
  MyModule.DoStuff();
  sinon.assert.calledOnce(spy);
});
```

If I spy on `console.log` however then it passes. I must be misunderstanding a very basic principle here, but I dont know what it is!

Is this something to do with the way my `module.exports` have been declared? So even though I am trying to spy on a top level export in my `index.js` (the `doOtherStuff: MyModule.doOtherStuff`), this is not what is actually being called internally when the call to DoStuff is being made in my test?

Comment: It looks like you’re spying on `ALClient`, not `MyModule`?

Comment: yeah sorry, that was a typo when i put this code snippet up. I have corrected this but the original problem remains. thanks

Comment: Did you mean to create an instance of MyModule first? In your example, `MyModule` does not have a `DoStuff` property, nor a `doOtherStuff` property that you can spy on. With the code you've shown, you *should* be seeing an "Attempted to wrap undefined property doOtherStuff" exception thrown by Sinon: http://jsfiddle.net/j7ksobce/1/. If you create an instance of `MyModule`, however, it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/qm0gj65o/

Comment: I do `require` in the module at the start of test spec file, so those properties are available when the test runs. I didnt show the require statement in my test spec snippet, I have added it now. I suspect if you followed the `module.exports` syntax it may start failing for you.

Comment: @mindparse I see where the disconnect is. In your first bit of example code, you do `MyModule = new MyModule();` before assigning `module.exports = MyModule;`. In your last example, you never call `new MyModule()`. Your two examples are fundamentally different.

Comment: in my second example, i just showed the re-written version of src/index.js, the top level index.js remained the same, with the `new` reference in. Sorry if that was unclear, but I have now accepted the answer thats just come in as it was down to what i was spying on not being what I thought

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Issue

The property wrapped in the `spy` is not the property that gets called.

### Details

`sinon.spy` takes an object and a property name and wraps the function at that property name in a spy.

In this case the object is the module export of `index.js`.

The module export is an object with two properties that point to methods on the inner `MyModule` instance created in `index.js`.  So the `doOtherStuff` property of that object is now a `spy` and the `DoStuff` property is still just a reference to the `DoStuff` property of the inner `MyModule` instance.

When the test then calls `MyModule.DoStuff()` it calls the `DoStuff` property of the inner `MyModule` instance which calls the `doOtherStuff` property of the inner `MyModule` instance which logs to the console.

The key point is that the `doOtherStuff` property of the inner `MyModule` instance got called directly and the `doOtherStuff` property of the object exported by `index.js` was never called.

The `spy` on the `doOtherStuff` property of the object exported by `index.js` then correctly asserts that it was called 0 times.

### Solution

Make sure the `spy` is created on the property that actually gets called.

The easiest way to do that in this case is to directly export the `MyModule` instance from `index.js`:

```
let MyModule = require('./src/index.js');

MyModule = new MyModule();

module.exports = MyModule;
```

Now when the `spy` is created it is created directly on the `doOtherStuff` property of the inner `MyModule` instance and will correctly report that it was called once.